# Performance issue in iterating a resultset

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

Our code is hosted in Websphere Application Server 8.5 64 bit on windows 2008 R2, target database is SQL Server 2008

Code:
[image: Code]

This servlet runs fine in iteration 1-5(1 millisecond) , but get worse and worse (5-8 seconds) for iteration 6-20. 
[image: perf result]

We looking to hear suggestions or comments for above strange behavior as we are doing same operation for all the 19 iterations.

Comment: Is the above code just an example or do you really want to return the value of the last row?

Comment: that's actually the production code.. thanks, please feel free comment..

Comment: If you only want a specific entry of the last row, then you could reverse the order by using `DESC` instead of `ASC` (or vice versa) and limit the result by appending `LIMIT 1`: `SELECT [desired column] FROM [table] ORDER BY [order by criteria] DESC [or ASC] LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Tom that code works on MySQL and Postgres. OP: for SQL Server, you should use `SELECT TOP 1 [columns] FROM ...`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I've never used SQL Server before, so I don't know any differences :D. Thank you, for that information.

Comment: You should provide the code here in the question to replicate the problem. Do not post images that shows your code. If you cannot share the exact production code, then provide an adaptation of it.

Comment: your missing the actual SQL which would be handy in trying to figure out what the issue is

Comment: As I know, `ResultSet` object is not just container of result entries. It wraps result dataset. So even you iterate over result set using `next()` it does not mean that sql query is completed. ResultSet receive rows when sql server find them. So I think, your problem is unefficient sql query.